# C# Graphics class want to make signature panel : input from drawing tablet

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

i am trying to make signature panel in c# windowsform application where input is from drawing tablet

my code as below this code working for line drawing not **dot** created.

So please suggest how **dot** and line both are create.

```
    {
        Graphics graphics;
        Boolean cusorMoving = false;
        Pen cursorPen;
        int cursorX = -1;
        int cursorY = -1;
       
        public SignPad()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            graphics = panel2.CreateGraphics();
            cursorPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            cursorPen.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
            cursorPen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
        }
```

Mouse Down event

```
        private void panel2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            cusorMoving = true;
            cursorX = e.X;
            cursorY = e.Y;
        }

        private void panel2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            cusorMoving = false;
           
            cursorX = -1;
            cursorY = -1;

        }
```

Mouse Move event

```
        private void panel2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cursorX != -1 && cursorY != -1 && cusorMoving == true)
            {
                graphics.DrawLine(cursorPen, new Point(cursorX, cursorY), e.Location);
                cursorX = e.X;
                cursorY = e.Y;
            }            
                         
        }
```

Comment: Duplicate of >10k posts.. - _graphics = panel2.CreateGraphics();_ - Never do this. Use the Paint event and its param `e.Graphics` for drawing onto a surface or create the graphics from a bitmap to draw into it. Yours will not be able to produce persistent results. - [Here]https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+doodle) are examples you may find useful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store individual points in a collection and draw them separately in the Paint handler. Every time you add a point to the collection, you also need to tell the panel to draw the area where the new segment was added. Something like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Lines
{
    public partial class SignPad : Form
    {
        Pen cursorPen = SystemPens.ControlText;
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        bool cursorMoving = false;

        public SignPad()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            cursorPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            cursorPen.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
            cursorPen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
        }

        private void panel2_Paint(object? sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var g = e.Graphics;
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            for (int i = 1; i < points.Count; ++i)
                g.DrawLine(cursorPen, points[i - 1], points[i]);
        }

        private void panel2_MouseDown(object? sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!cursorMoving)
            {
                cursorMoving = true;
                points.Clear();
                points.Add(e.Location);
                panel2.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void panel2_MouseMove(object? sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cursorMoving && points.Count > 0)
            {
                var p = e.Location;
                var q = points[points.Count - 1];
                var r = Rectangle.FromLTRB(Math.Min(p.X, q.X), Math.Min(p.Y, q.Y), Math.Max(p.X, q.X), Math.Max(p.Y, q.Y));
                r = Rectangle.Inflate(r, (int)cursorPen.Width, (int)cursorPen.Width);

                points.Add(p);
                panel2.Invalidate(r);
            }
        }

        private void panel2_MouseUp(object? sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            cursorMoving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the Paint handler the same way you added MouseMove, MouseDown and MouseUp handlers - in the Designer.

Comment: Hi, the purpose of the sample was to show the principle - separation of drawing from collecting points. Feel free to modify it to suit your needs.